# unable to open local pdf file via custom url protocol

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe, protocol-handler, custom-url-protocol

I have created a protocol handler to open acrobat reader dc . So as soon as a link in my webapp is clicked I am trying to launch acrobat with the local pdf file .

mypdf:c:\test\form.pdf this is the url I hit

This is the command in the protocol handler given :
"acrobat.exe"  /A "zoom=1000"  "%1"

But is says the "there was an error opening document the file name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

when replacing %1 with c:\test\form.pdf in registry acrobat reader opens the file with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is probably encoding the back slashes - try forward slashes instead
`mypdf:c:/test/form.pdf`